# How to set the default text value of a columnfilter for the datatables jquery api

Tags: jquery, datatables

How can I set the default text value for the input field for the columnfilter plugin for the datatables api?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

         var t1 = $( '#test').dataTable({

         }).columnFilter();
```

My table has several columns and I have tried setting the input box to have a default serach value as:

```
 $("input:eq(6)").val("myDefaultValue");
```

But this just displays myDefultValue in the search box , but doe not apply the filter.

I also tried triggering change and keydown, but both fail.

I am testing in Chrome, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for my first post. I red wrong the api doc.

See this page : [http://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/column%28%29.search%28%29)

You need to select the column and then use the `search()` method.

```
$( '#test')
    .columns(6) // to select the sixth column
    .search('myDefaultValue')
    .draw();
```

It should work better.

I delete my first post.

Comment: This works also! Thanks, and as you point it is a cleaner solution, which directly exploits the existing API.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Following the idea from Msieur Toph to try to trigger the search event, I have found the solution (by looking at the columnfilter source code), which is to trigger the keyup event.

$("input:eq(6)").val("myDefaultVal").trigger('keyup');

Comment: As I said in the new post I have made, he should better use the  `search` function on the column. Your solution propably works (I guess it does the exact same thing), but it is kind of dirty, no ? I think it is better to use the native API methods.